# Product loads wrong template (and url) when click on it from home in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have 2 templates in my store. Depending on category it loads a different template.
The problem is that at home page, the newest products loaded points to www.site.com/some-product.html that *always* loads the default template on the first visit.

If the user visits the product on it category (some-categ/same-product.html) it loads right, and if he goes back to home, and click again in the same product, it still loads right.

What can I do to make sure that the product always loads the right template in this case?
I am using magento 1.6.1 and template is assigned to the category, and the product have only one category.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the template or doing a layput update in the product itself rather than indirectly via categories?

Comment: Hi @JimOHalloran. Yes I tried. It works. But it will be a problem, because most of these new products will have new layout. It will be painfull to do this for every product... Do you have any idea?